# Is it possible to force "https only" in my Back4App app?

Tags: back4app

When the webhosting option is activated for an app in Back4App, getting a subdomain like `http://someapp.back4app.io`, if you access `someapp.back4app.io` http is used by default instead of https.

Regarding to this I only found https://blog.back4app.com/2017/11/09/parse-server-best-practices/ but that speaks only about checking via javascript the http/https protocol in every page/function/api-endpoint, and redirecting if it's not https, quite tedious.

Is there a way to globally redirect any http request to my Back4App pages to https?

Comment: The default API address is "https://parseapi.back4app.com/" (with https) but, if you like to use your own domain, you should check your DNS provider.

Comment: Sorry it seems the question was not clear enough, I've edited it for clarification, I'm refering to when activating the webhosting option, and accessing static pages there through a subdomain like `someapp.back4app.io`, which defaults to http instead of https

Comment: I checked with the Back4app's Support Team and, in that case, it's possible to do only on Dedicated Plans. For more info, I kindly ask you to contact them.

Comment: Thanks RamosCharles, if you put that as an answer I'll make it the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with the Back4app's Support Team and, in that case, it's possible to do only on Dedicated Plans. For more info, I kindly ask you to contact them.